# Passing parameters from middleware to controller - asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I need to pass some parameters from middleware to controller and I'm confused which approach should I use if I have to take care of performance, resource usage and security.

- `context.Items["user-id"] = "12345";`
- `context.Session.SetInt32("user-id", 12345);`

(It is the requirement to keep the Session enabled anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass it as an http header down the pipeline with the request

```cs
public class UserHeaderMiddleware  
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("user-id", new[] { userId.ToString() });
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: apparently it would be the third option to do that but it's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib yeah, sorry. Missed that you said you needed to stick with the session. I leave this answer here as it still has a point, IMO

Comment: Ya you have provided a third way to do that which can also be helpful for future visitors. Session is available already I don't need to stuck with it. I have two (now three) choices to transfer parameters to controllers and I have to pick best one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store the user ID for the future, session is the way to go. `Items` only passes it along for that request.